# .find() Jquery Function Is not supported in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Working with a Kendo grid, I need a method that checks data for a specific cell on the grid. I want to return the column name of which the cell is located on. The columns have a static field name, but dynamic title. I need to retrieve the title, based on the field name.

Code:

```
function checkAllTemperatures(data) {
    var columns = ['Temp1','Temp2','Temp3','Temp4','Temp5'];
    var comment = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        comment += checkTemperature(data, columns[i]) + ', ';
    }

    //removes trailing comma and whitespace from comment
    comment = comment.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
    setComment(data, comment);
}

function checkTemperature(data, columnName) {
    var comment = '';
    var matlSpec = GetMaterialSpecs(data.ProductId);
    var changedData = data[columnName];

    if(changedData > matlSpec.TemperatureUpperLimit || changedData < matlSpec.TemperatureLowerLimit)
    {
        var columnTitle = grid.columns.find(function(v, i) { return grid.columns[i].field == columnName; }).title;

        comment = columnTitle  + ' = ' + changeData;
        CommonFunctions.OpenErrorWindow({message: 'Temp is out of specification!', Errors:'', errors:''});
    }

    return comment;
}
```

When debugging in Google Chrome, running this command in the console: `grid.columns.find(function(v, i) { return grid.columns[i].field == "Temp1"; }).title` returns the correct title, but when running in IE11 I get this error:

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

Dispite that command working in the Chrome Console, when actually running the program chrome gives this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: changeData is not defined

Ideas of why this code breaks:

1) Jquery is being initialized twice because of the kendo grid, breaking it.

2) .find() is not supported by IE11

Any ideas to fix?

Comment: The second error is because of a typo (you initialize changedData and after that use changeData (note the missing d)

Comment: The first error is because `grid.columns` is not a jQuery object, but a regular array

Comment: instead of `find()` you could use `filter().pop()` instead. This is at least supported for IE11 (as well as all modern browsers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a polyfill for the Array.find method [towards the bottom of this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Array.find is not supported by IE at any point. Edge does support it though.